# Windows: Copying files using wildcard directories

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

We have a third party app that stores data to directories by date (and then by instance) and we want to copy the *.csv files from that directory to a server.  We only want the data from the instance directories -- nothing higher, nothing lower.

Example structure (ItemX is the instance and there can be child directories):

```
C:\APP
------ Machine1
------ -------- Data
------ -------- ---- 081209
------ -------- ---- ------ Item1 -> report.csv
------ -------- ---- ------ Item2 -> report.csv
------ -------- ---- 081109
------ -------- ---- ------ Item1 -> report.csv
------ -------- ---- ------ Item2 -> report.csv
------ Machine2
------ -------- Data
------ -------- ---- 081209
------ -------- ---- ------ Item1 -> report.csv
------ -------- ---- ------ Item2 -> report.csv
------ -------- ---- 081109
------ -------- ---- ------ Item1 -> report.csv
------ -------- ---- ------ Item2 -> report.csv
```

Is there a generic way to write this so that we can just create one script instead of one per machine?

Answer (score 1):

If the machineX is the name of the machine you can use the environment variable %COMPUTERNAME%

something similar to

```
xcopy c:\app\%computername%\Data\*\Item?\*.csv target\* /s
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of potentially doing it.  It's not quite command-line, but it can be called from a command-line:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace MachineInstanceCopyThing
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main ()
        {
            string AppDir = @"C:\App";
            string TargetDir = @"W:\Dest";

            if (!Directory.Exists (AppDir))
            {
                // do something to report the error
                return;
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists (TargetDir))
            {
                // do something to report the error
                return;
            }

            DirectoryInfo AppDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo (AppDir);

            // iterate through machine folders
            foreach (DirectoryInfo MachineDirectory in AppDirInfo.GetDirectories ())
            {
                string DataPath = MachineDirectory.FullName + @"\data";

                if (!Directory.Exists (DataPath))
                {
                    // do something to report the error
                    continue;
                }

                DirectoryInfo DataDir = new DirectoryInfo (DataPath);

                // iterate through date directories
                foreach (DirectoryInfo DateDirectory in DataDir.GetDirectories ())
                {
                    // iterate through instance directories
                    foreach (DirectoryInfo InstanceDirectory in DateDirectory.GetDirectories ())
                    {
                        string TargetPath = TargetDir + @"\" + InstanceDirectory.Name;

                        // create instance directory at the target
                        Directory.CreateDirectory (TargetPath);

                        foreach (FileInfo CSVFile in InstanceDirectory.GetFiles ("*.csv"))
                        {
                            File.Copy (CSVFile.FullName, TargetPath + @"\" + CSVFile.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't do much in the way of error checking aside from ensuring that the source and target exist.

Comment: I've got something similar...